# Running Groovy app

Tags: groovy, compilation

I just installed Groovy/Grail Suit for Eclipse in order to execute Groovy code. So, I created Java project (that is the only option I get) and wrote main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

def y = 9

}
```

By the way, eclipse does not allow to convert Java project into Groovy one.

But the line `def y = 9` produces syntax error. I am not quite sure what is the prob. Do I need to enable the Groovy on Eclipse or something? Once the plug-in has been installed the IDE restarted.
Best regards

Comment: There is some plugin on eclipse market to develop grailsApplication. You can find the IDE based on eclipse developped by Spring on their site.

Comment: I have already installed a plug-in. I am totally new to this language. If Groovy and Grail stand for different things so I need Groovy

Comment: Maybe you should start using the groovyConsole. And yeah Grails is a framework based on J2EE and groovy. Generally used for web application. Groovy is a language based on java and JVM. If you have no preferences for use IDE maybe look around intelliJidea too.

Comment: There is plug-in for eclipse and it shall work. I have NetBeans on my laptop. I could try Groovy out on it.

Comment: What is the name of this file you're trying to compile?

Comment: On my Eclipse installation I install Groovy-Eclipse plugin. I used the eclipse marketplace embedded in Eclipse and I can create groovy project after this installation.

Comment: The file name is Groovy.java. Firstly I have installed Groovy-eclipse plug in, but it did not let me compile the file.